# Socket programming implementation using Flask

Tags: flask, websocket, client-server

I have a Flask web application running on my First PC. Now I want two browsers running on two different computers to connect to this first PC using Socket Programming and request for a web page which is stored on First PC.Now first PC act as Server and Two other PCs act as Clients. I want these two clients to register themselves at server using registration web page and then send message to each other via server.
So what i want is to design a chat application using three PCs ,one of them act as server and other two act as clients.Server must be implemented in Flask.

Help me finding resources from where i could learn to implement this .

Answer (score 2):

Hi you might want to expose the link to clients by not running it from local host or using ngrok, however to implement the bi-directional communication take a read on [Flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) official documentation and also look through this [code repository by Miguel Grinberg](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO-Chat) which has a simple chat application using flask-socketio.

I hope this helps you...

Comment: This project is just for learning new tech under flask.So i have no worry of exposing anything to anyone.Thank you for your help

Comment: You are welcome hey i hope that it works feel free to ask for any issues